# Intellij recognizes TestNG annotation @Test but not (priority = #)

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, testng

I added TestNG to my pom.xml and it was imported. I'm able to use TestNG annotations, however when I try to set priority it does not recognize it. Is there something I'm missing here? Here is the version of Intellij I'm using:

IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-202.6397.94, built on July 27, 2020
Runtime version: 11.0.7+10-b944.20 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1088M
Cores: 8
Registry: debugger.watches.in.variables=false
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.andrey4623.rainbowcsv, training, net.seesharpsoft.intellij.plugins.csv, mobi.hsz.idea.gitignore, org.jetbrains.kotlin, com.easywsdl.tools.plugins.intellij, com.jetbrains.edu, com.alibaba.autonavi.qa.testng

This is the maven dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.3.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

This is what I see when I try to use the priority setting:

[image]

I'm fairly certain this might be fixed by importing the following dependency, however if I try to add it at the top of my class file it gives me the red squiggly and says it does not belong:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
```

Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your `import` section you are importing annotation `org.junit.Test`. Change it to TestNG annotation and this will help.

Just remove junit import and let Idea to suggest you to import the required class. Since you have both JUnit and TestNG it will prompt to pick which one your want to use.

Another option is to remove JUnit dependency from your project. In such case there would be no ambiguity so that Idea would generate the proper import automatically.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I should have caught that knowing that intellij's first assumption is to go with junit.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
import org.junit.Test
```

with

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test
```